# What is the meaning of "Forever Fornever" at the end of the anime series?

Tags: yu-yu-hakusho

The message "Forever Fornever" appeared at the end of the *Yu Yu Hakusho* anime series.

What does this mean and/or what is this related to?

> [image: FOREVER FORNEVER]

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090121160809AAKaWyP) opinion on the subject

Answer (score 3):

There is **no definite answer** for this question stated by the artist himself [Yoshihiro Togashi](http://yuyuhakusho.wikia.com/wiki/Yoshihiro_Togashi) There for we are left to interpreted it as we like. And there for there are allot of theory's of what this means. One of the most popular being the one stated by [Kakashi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/3081/kakashi)

> "Forever will not occur," or in other words, "nothing lasts forever." I believe that Yu Yu Hakusho was by far one of the greatest anime/manga ever written, and the artist knew that everyone watching the last few minutes of the final show never wanted it to end. But, since everything good thing must come to an end, the artist made it clear and simple. I believe this is the only anime to end with a phrase for viewers to think about, rather then simply saying "the end."

Another very popular theory is him showing discontinuation of the series. So no more different time lines, other endings. Or any such things.

But just like stated in the begin there is no definite answer given by the author himself.

Comment: Can you link (and quote) the source where Togashi says there is no definite answer? I clicked the author link above, but have not found any statements regarding the phrase

Comment: @krikara I regretfully have to say I cant find it anymore ;(

Comment: @kirkara what kind of answer were you expecting??? I am curious to know your thoughts

Comment: @Kakashi Just some sort of evidence that indicates that there is no definite answer. If Dimitri had that link where the artist himself made the statement, that would be marked correct.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this on [a forum](http://www.pojo.biz/board/showthread.php?t=455800),

> You raise a very interesting question that I'm sure has perplexed many fans. There have been a lot of discussions regarding it. First of all, the words "forever" and "fornever" are complete opposites of each other. Forever means that something will occur continuously, while **[fornever](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fornever)**, not actually being a word in the english dictionary but rather a **slang term**, means thats something will never occur.
>
> A common thing I hear is people believe that it is a typo and that is should state "**forever forever**". I personally don't think this is valid because the artist would certainly not screw up the last frame of the series.
>
> Personally, I believe that it just simply means what is says:"Forever will not occur," or in other words, "nothing lasts forever." I believe that Yu Yu Hakusho was by far one of the greatest anime/manga ever written, and the artist knew that everyone watching the last few minutes of the final show never wanted it to end. But, since everything good thing must come to an end, the artist made it clear and simple. I believe this is the only anime to end with a phrase for viewers to think about, rather then simply saying "the end."

Comment: This exact post has been posted before and deleted lol. I guess it is better that you cited your source, but there is still no substantial evidence behind this claim.

Comment: i was the one who wrote this thing 6 years back in the same forum....... and the given statement has a deeper meaning for wch i came up with my own understanding

Comment: @krikara to be honest,the term has got a deeper meaning in it.....initially i was unable to write it in words....this was the best explanation i could ever come up with.....and i was the person who initially deleted it due to the lack of evidence in my own answer ....but more than the evidence,i thought of concentrating the meaning of these words for wch i posted back my answer again

Answer (score 0):

It's just a phrase. Forever means that Yusuke's friendship will not end but other things will have to have a bound. It's also known as a schmaltz, like leaving a caption to leave the audience feeling good.

Comment: Sources and references always make for a good answer or to back up a claim/opinion. :)

Answer (score 0):

Forever, as in saying it will continue on in our hearts, and we will never forget this journey we went on with the characters. Fornever as in saying all good things come to an end, and no matter how much we reminisce on the good times, it will end eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I think he used Kuwabara to explain the meaning. When they are standing on the steps before heading to the beach, he talks about everything they all went through, and having that journey come to an end (Fornever). Then Kurama explains they can always remember the journey when they need to (Forever).